# Open SAP with Python GUI Script win32com.client.Dispatch("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")

Tags: python, user-interface, scripting, sap-gui

I made a script to open SAP GUI with Python.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
#reference sapfewse.ocx like a dll file with makepy()
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
conn = app.OpenConnection("System_Name", True)
ses = conn.Children
```

I am able to open the SAP GUI Scripting window with the code but, I think there is a problem with the `Children(0)` part as it does not allow me to use the `ses.FindByID` to access the ID tags.

Any tips?

Comment: import sys
from win32com.client import makepy

Comment: sys.argv = ["makepy", r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfewse.ocx"]
makepy.main()

Answer (score 1):

I believe for some reason makepy doesn't resolve the inheritance of the classes in the SAP dll correctly. You have to make sure you clean out your gencache of any files generated for the SAP dll, then dispatch the `Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1` dynamically.

```
import win32com.client as win32

app = win32.dynamic.Dispatch("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
```